# Divisibility of $n$ and $n^2$?

Tags: divisibility, proof-explanation

We're trying to prove that if $n$ is a positive odd integer then $n^2$ must also be an odd integer using an indirect evidence.

My textbook states that:

If we imagine that $n^2$ is divisible by two then $n$ is divisible by two, thus we can't arrive at this conclusion with an odd number as a starting point.

I don't get this.

If $n^2$ is an even number it means it's divisible by two. By dividing $n^2$ by two we get the positive integer $x$.

$$\frac{n^2}{2}=x$$
$$n^2=2x$$
$$n=\sqrt{2x}$$
$$n=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x}$$
$$\frac{n}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\frac{n}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}$$

Exactly how does it follow that $n$ is divisible by two?

If I am missing something elementary then please point me to a tutorial, thanks.

Comment: If $p$ is a prime and $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b.$

Comment: If that's really all your textbook says, then the book is not much help. But your argument is probably not what they meant in the book - elementary number theory of integer divisibility tends not to use $\sqrt{\cdot}$.

Comment: ehrrrm....what's that straight vertical line?

Comment: "*what's that straight vertical line*"  For positive natural numbers $a$ and $b$ we define $a\mid b$ (*read aloud as "a divides b"*) as meaning there exists an integer $k$ such that $a\cdot k=b$.  E.g. $2\mid n$ iff $n$ is even.    Depending on how you were trained, using division, fractions, square roots, and other operations which are not necessarily defined *for all* natural numbers that result in natural numbers in arguments such as these are often frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

If a prime number divides a product, then it divides one of the factors. It follows that, if $2$ divides $n^2=n \cdot n$, then $2$ divides $n$.

Comment: So if $\frac{n}{2}*n=x$ then $\frac{n}{2}=x$?

Comment: @Magnus: unfortunately, I do not understand your comment. What I understand is that someone here downvoted a *completely correct* answer. Ok, whatever...

Comment: I make a point not to downvote answers ^^

Comment: There is no point here. "If a prime number divides a product, then it divides one of the factors" is the ground zero of arithmetic. I repeat, whatever...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma

Comment: I mostly have a problem with that first sentence. Google points towards "Euclid's lemma".

Comment: I do not understand your comments,  sorry. It is surely my fault.

Answer (score 0):

An arbitrary odd integer is given by $2k + 1, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore an odd integer squared is $(2k + 1)^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1$. For all $k, 2*k$ is an even integer so therefore is follows that so is $4*k$. Adding one to an even integer makes it odd by definition. Therefore $4k^2 + 4k + 1$ must give an odd integer

Comment: this is my proof which i have deleted

Answer (score 0):

$2$ is a prime number and when a prime number $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$

From this we have that $2|n^2=nn \Rightarrow 2|n$

> You want to prove that if $a^2$ is even the $a$ is even.

So assume that $a$ is not even thus $a$ must be odd then $a=2k+1$ for some integet $k$ thus $$(2k+1)^2=4k^2+4k+1=2(2k^2+2k)+1=2s+1$$ for $s=2k^2+2k \in Z$ proving that $a^2$ is odd thus $a^2$ is not even which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Facts:

$$\color{Green}{n^2=n+n(n-1)}$$

- *product of any two consecutive integers is always even*.
- *sum of two even integers is always even*.
- *sum of odd integer and even integer is odd*.